# Which Python packages aren't used in application

Tags: python, package

Can you recommend a CLI / python package to tell me which modules aren't being imported into my application?

I considered using coverage + nosetests, but many of the unwanted/not needed packages have tests (to the credit of the previous developer).

As background, I'm dealing with a legacy code base and want to remove what isn't being used so far so I can reduce my mental load before a refactor.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Python module called [`vulture`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vulture) for doing exactly this. I haven't used it, but:

> Vulture finds unused classes, functions and variables in your code.

Comment: Just tried it, it works within modules and that's very useful. I was looking for an application-wide tree-like thing. Maybe I'm asking for a little too much...

Comment: BTW Alex, the Vulture package is kind of cute. It has a function called "scavenge", lol.

Comment: Hey, Vulture dev here. I'm curious, can you elaborate what do you mean by 'application-wide-tree-like-thing'?